# How to fully wrap an arbitrary element?

Tags: css

How can I fully wrap an arbitrary element with a `<span>` or `<div>`? By "fully" I mean I want its bounding box to fully contain whatever's inside.

In the example below, I put a `<span>` around an `<input>`, but as you can see from the screenshot, the `<span>` actually sits *inside* the `<input>` and doesn't fully contain it.

[image]

If I change the `<span>` to a `<div>` then it wraps the `<input>` just fine, but `<div>`s are 100% width by default, and the inner element isn't necessarily full-width, so that doesn't work either!

So how can I tightly wrap an arbitrary element?

---

Here's some code. You'll have to use DevTools to inspect the `.wrapper` spans to see if they fully contain the contents or not.

```css
.wrapper {
   /* what styles can I use here to wrap arbitrary elements? */  
}

.wideinput {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="wrapper">
  <input class="wideinput">
</span>

<span class="wrapper">
  <input class="narrowinput">
</span>

<span class="wrapper">
  <span>text</span>
</span>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block`?

Comment: @ceejayoz Nope. That changes the width of `.wideinput`.

Comment: [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) sounds like what I want, but not even Chrome supports it.

Comment: What about `display: inline-flex;align-items: center;` for the wrapper element?

Comment: @AlonEitan Also changes the width of `wideinput`. Anything `inline` seems to shrink `wideinput`, and anything `block` will be too wide or break the flow. I'm beginning to think there is no solution until [`contents`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-contents) is implemented, if it does what I think it does, and `getBoundingClientRect` works with it.

Comment: is the same happening if you use a div instead of a span? i am not sure if it is allowed to use input inside span

Comment: @StefanVilbrandt As I explained before, if I use a `<div>` it won't *tightly* wrap arbitrary contents. i.e., putting it around an inline element like a span will cause it to become a block-level element, which I also don't want.

Comment: @mpen - did you look into `max-width: max-content;`? [Here's an interesting article](http://thenewcode.com/894/Shrink-Wrap-HTML-containers-with-max-content) that discusses it. Seems it's supported by everything but IE, and there are fallbacks for IE.

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper No, I didn't look into that. Never heard of that before. That's really cool, but it doesn't look like it behaves the way I'd like either. If you add `width:max-content;display:block` to my snippet above you can see that it still affects the width of its children. The goal is to not tamper with the children at all.